# Variational argument with probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mathscr M(\mathbb Z^d)$ denote the set of probability measures on $\mathbb Z^d$

Let $\mu \in \mathscr M(\mathbb Z^{d+1}), $. Let $\mu_d $ be the marginal distribution $\sum_{z\in \mathbb Z}\mu(x,z)$ for $x\in \mathbb Z^d$ and $\mu_1=\sum_{x\in \mathbb Z^d}\mu(x,z)$ for $z\in \mathbb Z$.

Let $f_d$ be some function which takes measures where the index denotes the dimension of the measure.

Assume we have $$f_{d+1}(\mu) \ge \sum_{x\in \mathbb Z^d} \mu_d(x)f_1(\frac {\mu(x,.)}{\mu_d(x)})+\sum_{z\in \mathbb Z} \mu_1(z)f_d(\frac {\mu(.,z)}{\mu_1(z)})$$

My question is: how can I conclude from there that

$$\inf_{\nu\in \mathscr M^{d+1}} f_{d+1}(\nu)\ge
\inf_{\nu\in\mathscr M^1} f_1(\nu)
+\inf_{\nu \in \mathscr M^d} f_d(\nu)$$

The book I am reading says "varying over $\mu$" but I don't know what they mean by this.

It seems reasonable as $\mu_d(x)$ summed over all $x$ equals 1 and thus we want to minimize the first coordinate in the first sum and vice versa in the second one, but what would be the formal proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are on the right track.

Look at the first term on the RHS of the first inequality (the condition on $f$). Simply note that for any particular $\phi\in M_1$, we have $f(\phi)\ge\inf_{\nu\in M_1}f(\nu)$, but also note that for each $x$, $\mu(x,\cdot)/\mu_d(x)$ is just a $\phi\in M_1$, hence is no smaller than $\inf_{\nu\in M_1} f(\nu)$. So the first term satisfies 
$$\sum_{x\in \Bbb Z^d}\mu_d(x)\color{red}{f(\frac{\mu(x,\cdot)}{\mu_d(x)})}\ge\sum_{x\in \Bbb Z^d}\mu_d(x)\color{red}{\inf_{\nu\in M_1}f(\nu)}=(\sum_{x\in \Bbb Z^d}\mu_d(x))\cdot\color{red}{\inf_{\nu\in M_1}f(\nu)}=1\cdot\color{red}{\inf_{\nu\in M_1}f(\nu)}$$
 And for the second term it's all similar.

Comment: Thank you very much! So we have $\sum_{x\in \mathbb Z^d} \mu_d(x)f_1(\frac {\mu(x,\cdot)}{\mu_d(x)})+\sum_{z\in \mathbb Z} \mu_1(z)f_d(\frac {\mu(\cdot,z)}{\mu_1(z)})
\ge
\inf_{\nu\in\mathscr M^1} f_1(\nu)
+\inf_{\nu \in \mathscr M^d} f_d(\nu)$
But how do we know that 
$\inf_{\nu\in \mathscr M^{d+1}} f_{d+1}(\nu)$ is still bigger than the RHS?

Comment: @PeterGarder well, you have that for **any** $\mu\in M_{d+1}$, $$f(\mu)\ge RHS\ge \inf_{\nu\in M_1}f(\nu)+\inf_{\nu\in M_d}f(\nu)$$ where the far right side doesn't depend on our choice of $\mu$ at all. Now vary $\mu$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Oh okay, I see it. Thanks again!